# LNK2019 Error when building with CMake + Ninja (Visual Studio) + Conan in Windows

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors, conan, ninja

I took the following steps in building [the Poco example of Conan](https://github.com/conan-io/examples/tree/master/libraries/poco/md5).

1. Launch a [Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell?view=vs-2019#windows-10). Cd to the folder and mkdir build && cd build
2. Install Conan libraries, conan install .. with the following profile:

   ```
   [settings]
   arch=x86_64
   arch_build=x86_64
   build_type=Debug
   compiler=Visual Studio
   compiler.runtime=MDd
   compiler.version=16
   os=Windows
   os_build=Windows
   [options]
   [build_requires]
   [env]
   ```
3. `cmake .. -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug && cmake --build .`

Then, I got the following linking errors:

```
md5.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl Poco::DigestEngine::digestToHex(class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > const &)" (?digestToHex@DigestEngine@Poco@@SA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@ABV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@4@@Z) referenced in function _main
md5.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Poco::MD5Engine::MD5Engine(void)" (??0MD5Engine@Poco@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
md5.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall Poco::MD5Engine::~MD5Engine(void)" (??1MD5Engine@Poco@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
md5.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class std::vector<unsigned char,class std::allocator<unsigned char> > const & __thiscall Poco::MD5Engine::digest(void)" (?digest@MD5Engine@Poco@@UAEABV?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@XZ) referenced in function _main
md5.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Poco::DigestOutputStream::DigestOutputStream(class Poco::DigestEngine &)" (??0DigestOutputStream@Poco@@QAE@AAVDigestEngine@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
md5.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall Poco::DigestOutputStream::~DigestOutputStream(void)" (??1DigestOutputStream@Poco@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Poco::DigestOutputStream::`vbase destructor'(void)" (??_DDigestOutputStream@Poco@@QAEXXZ)
md5.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Poco::DigestOutputStream::close(void)" (?close@DigestOutputStream@Poco@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main
```

Building is success if build with Visual Studio, `cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 16"` (or build with Ninja for header-only libraries)

Do I miss something? Maybe the Conan profile need somehow to be tuned? I checked the [Docs](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/build_system/ninja.html) on Conan and tried that, but no difference.

Comment: On Windows, you have to pass the configuration when building, the definition does not work like on Linux. Try running `cmake --build . --config Debug`

Comment: @uilianries Thank you, I tried.  It's the same linking error.  I think the `cmake --build . --config Debug` is for those multi-configuration buildsystems like Visual Studio. I generate codes for Ninja and build with Ninja, just use the compiler from Visual Studio.

Comment: True, I miss the part with Ninja. In this case, I would suggest you opening an issue to conan-io/examples directly.

Comment: Sure. I did raise an issue to the Conan team: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/10404